# GUI Toolkit in OpenGL

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, opengl, toolkit

I'd like to develop an application (in C++) similar to [Pure Data](http://puredata.info/), but with a cool GUI and a better documentation... Yes, something like [Max/MSP](http://cycling74.com/products/maxmspjitter/) or [Reaktor](http://www.native-instruments.com/#/en/products/producer/reaktor-5/), but free and open!

In order to create an appealing, reactive and portable interface I was thinking of using OpenGL.
In my mind there is something like [Blender GUI](http://www.studiorola.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/Yafaray31.jpg).

Before starting to develop my custom GUI toolkit I googled around in order to understand if there exist something that I could use, and I found:

- [Juce](http://www.rawmaterialsoftware.com/juce.php): it seems quite supported, but I didn't understand if you can only embed OpenGL canvas in your interface or it is possible to render all the widgets using OpenGL.
- [nUI](http://www.libnui.net/): it seems really cool and portable, but... Its forum is a desert, and it's really hard to find a tutorial!
- ceGUI, FLTK, GLUI: so flat and gray ;-) and any aren't still maintained.

Do you know other toolkit? As you understand I'm looking for a portable library (in C++), fast and supported.

The other possibility is developing from scratch my custom toolkit using SDL or Freeglut, in this case which could be the best solution?

P.S.:
Reading other threads about this topic I noticed that many devs suggest using Qt... Could Qt relies on OpenGL for rendering? Or it could *only* host OpenGL canvas? Anyway do you think is possible (with good performance) creating something like this in Qt:

- [Reaktor GUI example 1](http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3078/3085492972_9398093265.jpg)
- [Reaktor GUI example 2](http://www.jazzmutant.com/images/tutos/template_lurker01.jpg)
- [Blender Compositing example](http://blendipel.files.wordpress.com/2009/09/nodes_explained.png)

Comment: nUI does have some tutorials in its github repository (see Wiki tab).

Comment: @ergosys You're right, but as you can read here [nUI Wiki](https://github.com/libnui/nui3/wiki): <<This wiki is currently being salvaged from a backup of the original website so it is incomplete and many features are broken (no images, missing links, etc.). Please bear with us as we fix the problems...>>. Anyway thanks... I think I'll give it a try!

Comment: Ross Bencina's Audiomulch program fulfills some of the things you're describing interface-wise (although as a music/audio environment it's higher level than what you're proposing) and it uses Qt. You may want to get in touch with him.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a good openGL toolkit, they tend to get invented for a particular app and then sort of abandoned.

Yes Qt works very well with openGL, there is an openGL [QGlWidget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qglwidget.html) with full hardware acceleration (and optional links to openCL). You can have as many QGLwidgets as you like in a Qt app - each with their own openGL commands inside them.

You can also mix Qt and openGL in the same QGlWidget (http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq26-openglcanvas.html)

Slightly off topic: You can also select Qt to use openGL for all it's rendering - this is still a bit experimental but means that 2d Qt can be much faster on some embedded platforms like phones.
edit: To clarify -the entire app are still normal Qt but drawn with openGL commands 'under the hood'

Comment: Thanks Martin for your answer... So if I understand correct, with Qt is possible (as experimental way) using OpenGL to _render_ the widget graphics. This is could be nice... Or anyway there is the possibility to embedded many OpenGL widgets with custom and accelerated drawing logic inside.

Answer (score 1):

I like Clutter and MX.

See http://www.clutter-project.org/ and https://github.com/clutter-project/mx

Comment: I wrote Toonloop, a "live" stop motion editor, in Clutter. My main concern with Clutter is that they tend to deprecate their API, or at least they did it a lot in the past. I will move forward to Qt5 with QML and QtQuick if I write a new version of Toonloop in the future, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Qt 5.7 and up offers QtQuick Controls 2.0 in QML, which are implemented in OpenGL.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-index.html

Their API is very stable and works on Android, iOS, macOS, Windows, GNU/Linux, etc.

Here is a small hello world in a great book about QML. https://qmlbook.github.io/en/ch02/index.html#hello-world

You write JavaScript in QML and the QMake build system turns it into C++ object code.

```
import QtQuick 2.5

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360
    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Hello World"
    }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            Qt.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted. Qt Quick 2 might well be one of the best options for this.

Comment: It's simply because I posted this answer only 23 hours ago. Please vote for it!